# adding a current class to current menu item CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Just trying to add a class to the menu item of the current page so the user know what page they are currently on. But the background-image will not show. I am applying the class to the `<a>` but I have also added it to the  the `<li>`

```
 <div id="menu">
                    <ul id='foot'>

                        <li><a class="current" href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href='article-list.php?article_type=test0'>Page 0</a></li>
                        <li><a href='article-list.php?article_type=test'>Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='article-list.php?article_type=test2'>Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='chic.php?page=blogs_full'>Page 3</a></li>                       

                    </ul>


            </div>
```

Style Sheet:

```
#menu{height:51px;width:900px;background-image:url(../NEW_images/menu_bg.jpg);background-repeat:repeat-x;}
#menu ul{}
#menu li {display:inline;font: 20px  Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#menu a {background: url("../images/seperator.gif") bottom right no-repeat;color: #ccc;display: block;float: left;margin: 0;padding: 8px 20px;text-decoration: none;}
#menu a:hover {background: #2580a2 url("../NEW_images/li_bg.jpg") bottom center repeat-x;color: #fff;padding-bottom: 8px;padding: 8px 20px;}
.current{background: #2580a2 url(../NEW_images/li_bg.jpg) bottom center repeat-x;color: #fff;padding-bottom: 8px;padding: 8px 20px;}
#page_num{width:100%; text-align:center; margin:40px 0 20px 0;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to qualify your `.current` selector with `#menu a`, otherwise it gets overridden by that previous selector because `.current` alone isn't specific enough:

```
#menu a.current{background: #2580a2 url(../NEW_images/li_bg.jpg) bottom center repeat-x;color: #fff;padding-bottom: 8px;padding: 8px 20px;}
```

Your CSS could also use better formatting, it's pretty hard to read like this.

Comment: Thanks that was it! I tried a.current but that didnt work either. Not sure why that is not specific enough.

Comment: @Denoteone: because the ID selector `#menu` is more specific than using an element or class selector alone

Answer (score 0):

**WORDPRESS** has already the function, which adds `current_page_item` class to the current menu item, so just add like this in css:

```
.current_page_item {
background-color:yellow;
}
```